# Given the following memory map, assume that the register $t0 stores value 8 while $s0 contains 0xCAFEFACE. Solve these questions

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, endianness

[image: So here's my problem]

So for this exercise I can easily solve a), b), e).

As for c), I believe the answer would be 0xFFFF9ABC (9 is 1001 in binary with sign extension).
d) 0x00000078 (7 is 0111).
f) 0x12345678CABCDEF0.
g) error.
I'm doing some reviewing for the upcoming midterm so I would appreciate the correction on this.
Thanks.

Comment: f) is wrong, but probably just a typo. The byte written will be `CE` You can set up a debugger/simulator to try these yourself.

Comment: @Jester For f) i just took the first byte of 0xCAFEFACE, which is CA and store it in the first cell of the 2nd row. So the second row should be 0xCABCDEF0. Could you explain to me what you think it's wrong?

Comment: Because `sb` writes the least significant byte which is the `CE`.

Comment: @ErikEidt: This is tagged [mips], which historically was usually big-endian, although MARS and SPIM both simulate a little-endian MIPS.  (SPIM depending on host endianness.)  So they actually *can't* just try it in a simulator to check the results, unless they find a different simulator.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I thought it was RISC V. My bad..@PeterCordes